# Common header and footer in fossil

Tags: fossil

I have a master remote repository, and two local repositories.
However, it appears that changes to header/footer/css do not propagate throughout the repos.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fossil will treat the configuration of each of your repository interfaces (whatever you put in the header/footer/css etc) as something unrelated to the versioning of your files. This makes sense when you are working with repositories that you you are not the admin of. You will always be in control of the UI on your local machine (where you are by default the admin) and make it look and behave whichever way you want, even if you do not have priviliges to make the same changes to the central repo.

To propagate changes to the configuration (including the  header/footer/css etc) you can use the fossil configuration options. Just type `fossil configuration --help` to see how you can export, import and synchronize your configuration accross repositories.